# Python - Assign random string to CSV object cell

Tags: python

I am manipulating a csv file using python, and I need to assign a random value from the choice of three words to the cells.

```
import os, sys, glob

fourthColVal="Yes"

with open(mostRecentCSVFile) as csvFileObj:
    csvFileLines=csvFileObj.readlines()


csvFinalLines=[]

with open(os.path.join(destFolder,os.path.basename(mostRecentCSVFile)),"w") as writeCSVObj:
    for currLine in csvFileLines:
        currLineList=currLine.strip().split(",")
        currLineList[3]=fourthColVal
        currLineStr=""

        csvFinalLines.append(currLineStr+"\n")
    writeCSVObj.writelines(csvFinalLines)
```

Currently, I have assigned the fourth column a hard coded value of 'Yes' for every line of CSV file but I want to assign a random value of 'Yes', 'No' or 'Maybe'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `random.choice` for this purpose.

```
import random    
import time

random.seed(time.time())
currLineList[3] = random.choice(['Yes','No','Maybe'])
```

Comment: It picks the same value for all the rows. I want to assign random values to rows.

Comment: You added `random.choice(..)` inside the loop ?

Comment: use `currLineList = list(map(lambda _ : random.choice(['Yes','No','Maybe']), currLineList))` to get random value for each row of the column and also correct the next line to `currLineStr = ','.join(currLineList )`